# How can i move a label slowly in pyqt5? I want the label to move automatically (with a while True?)

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to know how to move slowly a label in pyqt5, lets say that the label is a object(an arrow,bullet, etc) of a game but the label has to move automatically all the course of the game

```
self.label_enemy = QLabel(self)
self.label_enemy.setGeometry(400, 50, 20, 20)
self.label_enemy.setStyleSheet("background-color: blue")
self.distancia_enemy = 4
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a [QPropertyAnimation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpropertyanimation.html), that allows you to set the animation start and end value of a specific *property* of a *target* object. In your case, the *target* is the label, while the *property* is the [pos](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#pos-prop) QProperty.

Remember some important things:

- if a widget is added to a layout, you cannot move it (in the example below I'm using an "animator container" widget, which contains the object that you're going to animate);
- only [**properties**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html) of QObjects (and their descendants, including QWidgets) can be used; this means that you can't use a QPropertyAnimation on an object that's not a subclass of QObject;
- if you want to animate any other property that's not provided by the object, you can "create" a new one with `object.setProperty('propertyName', value)`, or use the [`QtCore.pyqtProperty` decorator](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/qt_properties.html);
- be very careful with hardcoded positions, if the widget that contains the animation can change its size, you'll face some problems for sure (that's why I used a fixed size in my example)
- [QGraphicsScene](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html) (and its visualization widget QGraphicsView) is usually a better solution for animations like those you seem you're interested in, since they provide an advanced animation framework which, amongst other things, helps solving scale issues and mouse/keyboard interaction; unfortunately they require some advanced skills and patience to be understood and mastered.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class AnimationArea(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AnimationArea, self).__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(640, 480)
        self.enemy = QtWidgets.QLabel('X', self)
        self.enemyAnimation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.enemy, b'pos')
        # set a start value for the animation; if we don't provide this
        # the animation will use the end value as soon as it finishes.
        self.enemyAnimation.setStartValue(self.enemy.pos())
        # set an end value for the animation; this is always required.
        self.enemyAnimation.setEndValue(QtCore.QPoint(400, 200))
        self.enemyAnimation.setDuration(2000)

    def start(self):
        self.enemyAnimation.start()


class AniWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AniWindow, self).__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.animationArea = AnimationArea()
        layout.addWidget(self.animationArea)
        self.startButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Start')
        layout.addWidget(self.startButton)
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.animationArea.start)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    aniWindow = AniWindow()
    aniWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

For more complex paths there are two solutions.

### Group of linear animations

This uses [QSequentialAnimationGroup](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsequentialanimationgroup.html) which allows to concatenate multiple animations. The advantage is that you can set different speeds for each segment, but the will always be linear paths. Since the animations are sequential (and we're returning to the start position at the end), you only need to set the end values. This snippet will move your enemy around a triangle.

```
        self.enemyAnimation = QtCore.QSequentialAnimationGroup()
        first = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.label_enemy, b'pos')
        first.setEndValue(QtCore.QPoint(0, 400))
        first.setDuration(1000)
        second = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.label_enemy, b'pos')
        second.setEndValue(QtCore.QPoint(400, 400))
        second.setDuration(2000)
        third = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.label_enemy, b'pos')
        third.setEndValue(QtCore.QPoint(0, 0))
        third.setDuration(3000)
        self.enemyAnimation.addAnimation(first)
        self.enemyAnimation.addAnimation(second)
        self.enemyAnimation.addAnimation(third)
```

### Follow a path

A [QPainterPath](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html) can be used to draw more complex (and non linear) paths. For this approach you'll need to use [QVariantAnimation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariantanimation.html) going from `0.0` to `1.0`, and the [QPainterPath.pointAtPercent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html#pointAtPercent) function, that returns the coordinates at any percentage of the path. In this case I used a segment and a curve.

```
        self.enemyAnimation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation()
        # *BOTH* start and end values *HAVE* to be float!
        self.enemyAnimation.setStartValue(0.0)
        self.enemyAnimation.setEndValue(1.0)
        self.enemyAnimation.setDuration(2000)
        self.enemyPath = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        self.enemyPath.lineTo(100, 400)
        self.enemyPath.quadTo(400, 400, 400, 0)
        self.enemyAnimation.valueChanged.connect(self.moveEnemy)

    def moveEnemy(self, percent):
        self.label_enemy.move(self.enemyPath.pointAtPercent(percent).toPoint())
```